# my autocomplete jquery is not working on email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4

i am using this jquery in laravel boot strap form but jquery is not giving suggestion

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Email <span style="opacity: 0.5; font-style: italic;">(Required)</span></label>
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="autocomplete" id="email"  class="form-control input-lg  />

        <span id="error_email"></span>
        @if($errors->has('email'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ $errors->first('email') }}
        </div>
        @endif
      </div>
```

and it is jquery

```
var options = ['@gmail.com', '@msn.com', '@yahoo.com'];
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: options
});
$("input#autocomplete").keyup(function() {
    var new_options = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
    new_options[i] = $(this).val() + options[i];
    $(this).autocomplete( "option", "source", new_options);
});
```